# ASP.NET MVC Login through database

Tags: asp.net

I have a code here for login, it's working but as you can see, I hard coded the username and password, what I would like to do is to get from a database for accounts, preferably using RAW SQL not Entity framework, please help.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Form is not valid; please review and try again.";
        return View("Login");
    }

    if (login.Username == "bpradmin" && login.Password == "admin123")
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(login.Username, true);

    ViewBag.Error = "Credentials invalid. Please try again.";
    return View("Login");
}
```

Comment: You must have tried something, Have you created a database, Have you built the logic to connect to a database? Your question is missing a lot of vital information.

Comment: I think you should look into basic tutorials of Entity Framework - it will give you a clear understanding of connecting to DBs and performing CRUD operations easily

Comment: @TezWingfield I already have a database, I also know my connection string, but i don't know how to put it there

Comment: @Hanzou Please refer to Dawood Awan's comment and invest a significant amount of time into Entity Framework / CRUD operations.

Comment: You appear to be using plaintext passwords in your database. That is a bad idea. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted. If you didn't know this, this is a strong sign that you should not be rolling your own authentication framework.

Comment: @Hanzou Why not Entity Framework? Or any ORM? ADO/Raw SQL is so 90's haha I believe you'll enjoy the process much more using an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend Entity Framework. Then you should choose between Code First or Database First. This Framework is very easy to understand and you can do pretty cool things once you have understood the order of events. 
This link is a tutorial for Entity Framework
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Answer (score 0):

Write a Stored Procedure and call that through simple ADO.net Code

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConn=new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
     using(SqlCommand sqlCmd=new SqlCommand())
     {
         sqlCmd.Connection=sqlConn;
         sqlConn.Open();
         sqlCmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         sqlCmd.CommandText="Your SP name";
         sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName","bpradmin");
         sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Password","admin123");
         sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
         sqlConn.Close();
     }
}
```